# Is it possible to do an SQL query across two tables?

Tags: sql, many-to-many, join

I have a couple tables that look like this:

```
 ___________    ___________
| Books     |  | Tags      |
|-----------|  |-----------|
| book_id   |  | tag_id    |
| book_name |  | tag_name  |
 -----------    -----------
```

And a join table that connects the "many-to-many relationship":

```
 ___________
| Books/Tags|
|-----------|
| book_id   |
| tag_id    |
 -----------
```

I want to do a query that's kind of like this:

```
SELECT book_name, tag_name FROM books, tags WHERE tag_name = 'fiction'
```

Is there any way to "attach" the books table to the tags in the query since they have a join table between them?  Or do I have to do three queries, one to get the tag_id, another to get the book_id matching the tag_id, and a third to get the book_name matching the tag_id?

Comment: I don't really get your question. What ouput would you like?

Comment: Isn't tag_name in the SELECT columns redundant? It can only return 'fiction' which is what you are searching on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can do; with a JOIN:

```
SELECT b.book_name, t.tag_name FROM books b
JOIN books_tags bt ON bt.book_id=b.book_id
JOIN tags t ON t.tag_id=bt.tag_id
WHERE t.tag_name = 'fiction';
```

This will return a list of books which have the 'fiction' tag.

Alternatively you can do it with subqueries:

```
SELECT b.book_name FROM books b WHERE id IN (
    SELECT bt.book_id FROM books_tags bt
    WHERE bt.tag_id IN (
        SELECT t.tag_id FROM tags t WHERE t.tag_name='fiction'
    )
)
```

Or:

```
SELECT b.book_name FROM books b WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM books_tags bt
    JOIN tags t ON t.tag_id=bt.tag_id
    WHERE t.tag_name='fiction'
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do this in one query, this is called a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT book_name, tag_name FROM books
    JOIN bookTags ON books.book_id = bookTags.book_id
    JOIN tags ON booksTags.tag_id = tags.tag_id
    WHERE tag_name = 'fiction';
```

Answer (score 0):

you will need to join all three tables

```
SELECT books.book_name, books.tag_name FROM books, bookTags, Tags
WHERE books.book_id = bookTags.book_id
AND booksTags.tag_id = Tags.tag_id
and Tag.tag_name = 'fiction';
```